# java hibernate multiple persistent object?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having problems querying a table via hibernate.

I have a Customers POJO mapped into hibernate.

My files:

```
Customers.java
Customers.hbm.xml
hibernate.cfg.xml
```

I can query this object just fine, list, add, delete, etc.

Now I added another POJO class, Order, which I also created a table for in the database like the Customer POJO. (I made an exact copy and changed to 'Order' where 'Customer' was).

Now, from my main class ManageCustomer. I run this command:

```
public void listCustomer( ){
          Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          try{
             tx = session.beginTransaction();
             List customers = session.createQuery("FROM Customer").list(); 
             for (Iterator iterator = 
                               customers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
               Customer customer = (Customer) iterator.next(); 

               String tmpMessage = customer.getFirstName().toString();
               System.out.println("First Name: "+customer.getFirstName()+", Credit:  "+customer.getCreditBalance()+"\r\n");

             }
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }
       }
```

and everything works fine, i get all entries in the Customer table from the database.

Now when i tried to query the Order table, by making a second function (for testing)

```
public void listCustomer2( ){
          Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          try{
             tx = session.beginTransaction();
             List orders = session.createQuery("FROM Order").list(); 
             for (Iterator iterator = 
                               orders.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
              Order order = (Order) iterator.next(); 

               String tmpMessage = order.getFirstName().toString();
               System.out.println("First Name: "+order.getFirstName()+", Credit:  "+order.getCreditBalance()+"\r\n");

             }
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }
       }
```

it doesnt work.. can't query Order table. would appreciate if someone can point in right direction of the error.

thanks

error:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER order0_' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.hexs.net.ManageCustomer.listEmployees2(ManageCustomer.java:726)
    at com.hexs.net.ManageCustomer.handlePlayerListRequest(ManageCustomer.java:498)
    at com.hexs.net.ManageCustomer$ChatIncomingReader.run(ManageCustomer.java:552)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER order0_' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

The word **ORDER** is a reserved keyword used in `ORDER BY`. I'm not aware of any way to escape it properly in HQL. Renaming would be the safer option.

Comment: ah that could be doing it

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. The exception says so :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the table name from 'ORDER' to something else which is not a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, ORDER is a reserved keyword, in my case I was using several reserved words:

**Group**

**DP** - not sure but appears on here: [List of SQL reserved words](https://drupal.org/node/141051)

Also I was using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect (before that org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL) instead of org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect as my hibernate.dialect property.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[order]")
public class Order implements Serializable {
------------
}
```

thats the trick.

Comment: just write the entity name like i given "[order]" rather than "order". so, sql don't treat it as keyword and you will see order table is successfully created

Comment: Thanks, can you please edit the question and add the info.